# How to feed xargs to a piped grep for a piped cat command

Tags: bash, shell, grep, command, xargs

How to feed **xargs** to a **piped grep** for a **piped cat** command.

**Command 1:**
(Generates a grep pattern with unique PIDs for a particular date time, read from runtime.log)

```
cat runtime.log | grep -e '2018/09/13 14:50' | awk -F'[ ]' '{print $4}' | awk -F'PID=' '{print $2}' | sort -u | xargs -I % echo '2018/09/13 14:50.*PID='%
```

The output of above command is (It's custom grep pattern):

```
2018/09/13 14:50.*PID=13109
2018/09/13 14:50.*PID=14575
2018/09/13 14:50.*PID=15741
```

**Command 2:**
(Reads runtime.log and fetch the appropriate lines based on the grep pattern (Ideally the grep pattern should comes from command 1))

```
cat runtime.log | grep '2018/09/13 14:50.*PID=13109'
```

The question is **How to combine both Command 1 & Command 2**

Below combined version of command doesn't gives the expected output (The produced output had lines having the date other than '2018/09/13 14:50')

```
cat runtime.log | grep -e '2018/09/13 14:50' | awk -F'[ ]' '{print $4}' | awk -F'PID=' '{print $2}' | sort -u | xargs -I % echo '2018/09/13 14:50.*PID='% | cat runtime.log xargs grep
```

Comment: Better describe sample input and expected output.   
Please, read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Is `grep -f <(command 1)` what you are looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

grep has an option `-f`. From `man grep`:

> -f FILE, --file=FILE
>   Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line. The empty file contains zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing. (-f is specified by POSIX .)

So you could use

```
cat runtime.log | grep -e '2018/09/13 14:50' | awk -F'[ ]' '{print $4}' | awk -F'PID=' '{print $2}' | sort -u | xargs -I % echo '2018/09/13 14:50.*PID='% > a_temp_file
cat runtime.log | grep -f a_temp_file
```

The shell has a syntax that avoids having to create the temporary file. `<()`. From `man bash`:

> ### Process Substitution
>
> Process substitution is supported on systems that support named pipes
>   (FIFOs) or the /dev/fd method of naming open files. It takes the form
>   of <(list) or >(list). The process list is run with its input or
>   output connected to a FIFO or some file in /dev/fd. The name of this
>   file is passed as an argument to the current command as the result of
>   the expansion. If the >(list) form is used, writing to the file will
>   provide input for list. If the <(list) form is used, the file passed
>   as an argument should be read to obtain the output of list.

So you can combine it to:

```
cat runtime.log | grep -f <(cat runtime.log | grep -e '2018/09/13 14:50' | awk -F'[ ]' '{print $4}' | awk -F'PID=' '{print $2}' | sort -u | xargs -I % echo '2018/09/13 14:50.*PID='%)
```